# QSvgRenderer is using an older version of SVG

Tags: qt, svg

I am using the QSvgRenderer class to render an SVG in Qt. I am able to animate SVG's but ONLY using properties from an older version of SVG.

I am attempting to make B1 and B2 stroke fields flash using the most recent version of SVG animate, however only the deprecated animateColor works.

Below is a a snippet of the svg I am using with both following versions of the animation attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
              "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="1.24444in" height="1.54444in"
     viewBox="0 0 112 139">
  <path id="B1"
        fill="blue" stroke="none" stroke-width="3"
        d="M 17.08,8.91
           C 21.91,7.93 26.02,8.14 29.87,11.65
             37.10,18.27 34.53,30.65 25.08,33.61
             9.80,38.40 0.02,16.14 17.08,8.91 Z">
    <animateColor
                attributeName="stroke"
        from="red"
                to="white"
                dur="0.5s"
                repeatCount="indefinite"
                />
  </path>
  <path id="B2"
        fill="blue" stroke="none" stroke-width="3"
        d="M 51.19,9.17
           C 56.02,8.19 60.14,8.40 63.98,11.91
             71.21,18.53 68.65,30.91 59.19,33.87
             43.91,38.66 34.13,16.40 51.19,9.17 Z">
        <animate
             attributeType="XML"
             attributeName="fill"
             values="red;white"
             calcmode="discrete"
             dur="0.5s"
             repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
</svg>
```

When I open the image in Qt's image viewer I only see B1's stroke flashing. BUT when I open the SVG in chrome, I only see B2's stroke animation. Is this just a product of Qt's use of the SVG libraries? Or is there a package I need to update on my machine?

OS: Debian 10
Qt Creator: V4.14.0
Qt: 5.15.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/svgrendering.html#rendering-svg-files) points out:

> Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) is a language for describing two-dimensional graphics and graphical applications in XML. SVG 1.1 is a W3C Recommendation and forms the core of the current SVG developments in Qt. SVG 1.2 is the specification currently being developed by the SVG Working Group, and it is available in draft form. The Mobile SVG Profiles (SVG Basic and SVG Tiny) are aimed at resource-limited devices and are part of the 3GPP platform for third generation mobile phones. You can read more about SVG at About SVG.
>
> **Qt supports the static features of SVG 1.2 Tiny**. ECMA scripts and DOM manipulation are currently not supported.
> ...

That is, it supports a minimalist SVG standard.

A workaround is to use [`QWebEngineView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html) (or [`WebEngineView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineview.html) in QML) that uses chromium as a tool to render the same way that Google-Chrome does.